# VBA code to transpose a specific non-numeric data (column to row)?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'am currently trying to code on vba (2nd day) and I am having a hard time trying to find a code that can transpose the non numeric data (name, code, mnemonic) of column A to row number 1 for the first stock Fortnox (and the next ones 1712 stocks) as well as to copy the prices of each stock of column 1 to the respective column like you can see in the pictures..

By looking to these pictures you can figure out what I am asking! Thanks in advance for your help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the macro recorder feature in Excel - http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2010/

Answer (score 0):

In order from slowest and simplest to the fastest and most effecient:

**Option 1**

```
Range("A125:A127").Copy
Range("C1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
'Extrapolate for other copies
```

**Option 2**

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 3
    Cells(2, i + 2).Value = Cells(i + 124, 2).Value
Next i
```

Option 3 would be to get the `Value` of the range as a 2D array and swap the indexes, but I'm not *that* fancy.